# What should I define in the setContentView in MainActivity.java file?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to know what should come in the bolded part below.It shows me two options:

1.toolbar(The xml I created to add the code for the google appbar)

2.activity_main

The both seems to show no errors that why I want to know which one should I add.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.**toolbar**);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to set activity_main in setContentView because it can contain toolbar in it.

Comment: you should have a xml file name for the corresponding activity... I mean the xml file is where you design your view items like buttons, imageview etc etc.. something like this.. setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); where u find activity_main in res folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi add like this,

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.youractivity);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        mTitle.setText("Contact Us");
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
}

}
```

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


</RelativeLayout>
```

hope this will help you

Comment: `Utils.backarrow(activity)` probably won't compile. This answer could be much shorter as the up/back navigation isn't part of the question

Answer (score 0):

As Bansal mentioned correctly, you must use activity_main in setContentView.

Your activity_main.xml will contain the toolbar. Inside the toolbar tag you must call the toolbar layout. It uses your toolbar.xml layout for your toolbar.

Comment: The names of the XML files are arbitrary, though

Comment: Yes @cricket_007 . But these are the default names ( activity_main.xml, toolbar.xml). Obviously we can change them according to our needs.

Comment: Right. I was just commenting for OP, who doesn't seem to understand when either file should be used. The names could be reversed, for example, or the toolbar.xml could be an entire Activity layout with a Toolbar in it